# What is the best way to track, record or view search terms?

Tags: search, analytics

Pretty much like the title says - What is the best way to track, record or view search terms when using the built in [Search form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/search-form)?

Comment: We have been asked about this to the option to show recent searches and top searches. Anyone get anywhere with it?

Answer (score 9):

We track search terms on buildwithcraft.com the same way we track all other site activity: using Google Analytics.

All you have to do is throw GA event tracking code into your search results template.

If you’ve upgraded to Universal Analytics/analytics.js, use this:

```twig
{% set js %}
    ga('send', 'event', 'Search', 'Search', '{{ query|e("js") }}', {'nonInteraction': 1});
{% endset %}
{% includeJs js %}
```

If you’re still on the old ga.js, use this:

```twig
{% set js %}
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Search', 'Search', '{{ query|e("js") }}', null, true]);
{% endset %}
{% includeJs js %}
```

There are other ways to include the JS, of course. (In our case we actually have a blank `analytics` block right alongside other Google Analytics instantiating code in the layout template, and set this JS code by overriding that block on templates that have custom things to track.) This `{% includeJs %}` route is just the most unassuming.

With that code in place, you’ll be able to start tracking “Search” events from Behavior > Events in your Google Analytics dashboard.

Answer (score 4):

No built in way that I am aware of, but you could send the search query off to a custom plugin controller from your search template using ajax, which could either save it to a custom table (i.e. search_cache), or log them to a log file.

Answer (score 3):

Completely untested, but may work in theory... **Take a look into [template hooks](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#hook-detail).**

When the template loads, it will ping your hook and provide whatever Twig variables have already been set. Your custom plugin will have a chance to then record your search terms as needed.

Answer (score 2):

If your search page uses a query string, it's possible to enable search tracking from directly within Google Analytics. More details on Site Search [here].(https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en)

[image]